# HTML PHP Math : Fill a progress bar using rank values

Tags: php, html, math, progress-bar

I got a progress bar to be filled showing remaining rank points to next level.

Ex: got 25 points and next rank is at 50 points so the bar must to be filled at 50%, if i got 40 point must to be 75% filled etc.

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php print $rank; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php print get_rank($rank) * next_rank($level) / 2; ?>%;">
```

The `get_rank()` function take Rank points and convert to remain points minus `$rank` value, then I'd pass the `$rank` value to `level()` function in order to retrieve the level and finally `next_rank()` function get the level and return the remaining points.

So the used math is `(get_rank($rank) * next_rank($level) / 2) / 10`.

Using this return the remaining value ( eg. 19 * 20 / 2 = 500 / 10 = 19% ) print in the width 0.25%, how i can reverse the result to get 99.75% instead of 0.25?

For completeness will paste the complete functions:

```
 <?php 
function get_rank($rank) {
    if ( $rank >= 5    )  { $rem_point = 20   - $rank; }
    if ( $rank >= 20   )  { $rem_point = 50   - $rank; }
    if ( $rank >= 50   )  { $rem_point = 100  - $rank; }
    if ( $rank >= 100  )  { $rem_point = 500  - $rank; }
    if ( $rank >= 500  )  { $rem_point = 1000 - $rank; }
    if ( $rank >= 1000 )  { $rem_point = 2500 - $rank; }
    if ( $rank >= 2500 )  { $rem_point = 5000 - $rank; }

    return $rem_point;
}
function level($rank) {
        if ( $rank <= 5    )   { $level = 1; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 20   )   { $level = 2; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 50   )   { $level = 3; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 100  )   { $level = 4; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 500  )   { $level = 5; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 1000 )   { $level = 6; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 2500 )   { $level = 7; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 5000 )   { $level = 8; }

    return $level;
}
function next_rank($level) {
        if ( $level = 1 )     { $next_r = 5;      }
    elseif ( $level = 2 )     { $next_r = 20;     }
    elseif ( $level = 3 )     { $next_r = 50;     }
    elseif ( $level = 4 )     { $next_r = 100;    }
    elseif ( $level = 5 )     { $next_r = 500;    }
    elseif ( $level = 6 )     { $next_r = 1000;   }
    elseif ( $level = 7 )     { $next_r = 2500;   }
    elseif ( $level = 8 )     { $next_r = 5000;   }

    return $next_r;
}
?>
```

Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Zéychin The question, is how i can do the math expression to calculate the width value of the progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace `<?php print get_rank($rank) * next_rank($level) / 2; ?>`
   by `<?php print_r(($rank*100)/(get_rank($rank)+$rank)); ?>` should do the job you want.
2. For `function level($rank)` if i input `level(10)` output will be `10` as you are returning `$rank` without any calculation.

Comment: 2. can you explain how?

Comment: yes, `40` is `(40*100/50)%` of `50` if we want to find percentage of `x` with respect to `y`, then formula will be `(x*100/y)`. thanks. if this works, please accept the answer. thanks.